# How can I judge the class implement the Ordering in Scala

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class MyClass[K, V](val elements: Seq[(K, V)] {
   def myFunc() = {
       if (k is ordering) {
         MyProcess[K, V](elements)
       } else {
         otherthing
       }
   }
}


class MyProcess[K: Ordering, V](val content: Seq[(K, V)]) {
  //
}
```

I do not want to constraint the type K with `K:Ordering`, since under some condition, I do not want this, but How can I using the implicitly Ordering for type K in MyProcess?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the logic of what you're trying to do? This smells like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Perhaps with more information can further divide your problem and make it simpler.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's probably a bad idea to do this. But if you're really sure this is want you need, it is possible. You have to ask for an *optional* implicit value of `Ordering[K]`. This is however not available out-of-the-box.

*Disclaimer/warning: shameless self-promotion up ahead*

I recently pushed a library to github for playing around with some implicit resolution tricks. It contains an [`Optional` typeclass](https://github.com/Jasper-M/implicitlogic/blob/master/src/main/scala/implicitlogic/Optional.scala) that does what you are looking for.

Using it, your code would look like this:

```
import implicitlogic.Optional

class MyClass[K, V](val elements: Seq[(K, V)]) {
  def myFunc()(implicit opt: Optional[Ordering[K]]) = opt.result match {
    case Some(ordering) => new MyProcess[K, V](elements)(ordering)
    case None => otherthing
  }

  def otherthing = ???
}

class MyProcess[K: Ordering, V](val content: Seq[(K, V)])
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, seems good !
I just remove the ordering, and use the ```asInstanceOf[Comparable[K]]``` in the ```MyProcess``` class. 
I will look for your library later.

Comment: I've had success with `def myFunc()(implicit ord: Ordering[K] = null) = if (ord ne null) { ... } else { ... }` before.